# Implementing Google like menu using CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to implement the latest google like menu.. (When we open google left top we can see a Google Button. When I click on that button menu will appear and will stay until another click is happened on document. On hover of that element menu will appear and will live till mouseout. I want to implement the same and here is the code I have tried.. I hope I will get help here. I want to add the exact functionality like google menu(effects)

HTML

```
<div id="content1" style="width:50px">
<span class="header">Hello</span>
<ol id="a">
    <li><span class="ele">jkehfkje</span></li>
    <li><span class="ele">jkehfkje</span></li>
    <li><span class="ele">jkehfkje</span></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div>kufhjegfe</div>
```

jQuery code

```
$('#content1').hover(function() {
   $('#a').fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
   $('#a').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

CSS

```
#a
{
  display:none   
}
.ele
 {
   height:20px;
   width:60px;
   border:1px solid black;
 }
.ele:hover
{
  cursor:pointer
}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdDCj/) is the fiddle
Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with your code so far?

Comment: I want to implement the exact functionality like that Google menu..

Comment: That's great, but you've got to actually ask a question.

Comment: The click-based toggling display would require javascript. You could accomplish a hover-based display with pure CSS, but it wouldn't remain open when the mouse pointer exited the element, and wouldn't react to click events on other parts of the DOM. The javascript to make this happen is fairly simple, though, if you're interested.

Comment: My answer should help you, seems you're looking for `click()` and `toggle()`. It's important to note my use of `event.stopPropigation()` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using `toggle` like this:

```
 $('#content1').click(function(){
     $('#a').toggle('slow');
     event.stopPropagation(); //this is important
 });
```

Then somewhere put code that will close the menu if the user clicks somewhere else...

```
$('html').click(function(){
    if($('#a').is(':visible')) $('#a').toggle('slow');
});
```

If we don't include `event.stopPropagation();` as seen above, the `$('html').click()` will happen as well, which means it will both open and close the menu.

Hope this helps!

P.S. Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mkprogramming/zhdDC/

(I used a div called body instead of `html`)

Answer (score 2):

For starters, [here is a fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtrqv/). All I did was give your ol a position: absolute.

This causes the menu to not affect other content lower in the page flow.

Which google menu are you talking about? The MORE tab?

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your js to make menu click-based. Also prepared a function for hovering menu elements. I hope this will help.

```
    $('#content1').click(function() {
    $('#a').fadeIn('slow');
     event.stopPropagation(); 
});
$('.ele').hover(function(){

});
$('body').click(function(){
  $('#a').fadeOut('slow');});
```

Comment: This will not work. The body click will trigger as well. See my answer for the solution.

Comment: it actually works, because I'm using fadeIn and fadeOut separately. And you're using toggle. Toggle has that problem, but my case works too.

Comment: Not trying to be a pest, I tried it in jsFiddle and it isn't working correctly? did you test this code? Without the stopPropigation function I used in my answer it will fire both the content click and the body click at once.

Comment: oops, I'm sorry. I did test it and it worked, but I somehow forgot to refresh before that :D
Now after some "undo"-s that brought back my `event.stopPropagation();`, my code works again :)